# Time series plot with category names as text

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-charts

Let us say I have data like this for a spend summary sheet:

| Date | Amount | Category |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 03/31/2023 | 20.0 | Food |
| 03/31/2023 | 23.12 | Coffee |
| 03/31/2023 | 21.01 | Movie |
| 04/01/2023 | 10.0 | Coffee |
| 04/01/2023 | 12.0 | Coffee |
| 04/01/2023 | 13.12 | Food |
| 04/02/2023 | 10.0 | Movie |

I know how to get an aggregate plot by using the `Date` and `Amount` columns.

I would like a line plot of multiple lines, now for each category, within the same graph. i.e. for each category, I have a differently colored aggregate line plot. Here for eg, I'd have 3 different colored lines plot, one for `food`, one for `coffee` and one for `movie`, all within the same plot. I'd also like to have a line plot of all categories combined as well, in the same plot. Is such a thing possible in sheets?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do that is to pivot the data so that Food, Coffee and Movie each have their own column, like this:

```
=query( 
  A1:C, 
  "select A, sum(B) 
    where B is not null 
    group by A 
    pivot C", 
  1 
)
```

Then plot the result table instead of the original. Use a stacked column chart to view how total develops over time.

If you absolutely want to add a separate totals figure, use this pattern:

```
=let( 
  data, 
    query( 
      A1:C, 
      "select A, sum(B) 
       where B is not null 
       group by A 
       pivot C", 
      1 
    ), 
  rowsum_, lambda(row, iferror(sum(row) - single(row), "Total")), 
  { data, byrow(data, rowsum_) } 
)
```

You can move the Total series to the Right axis so that its scale does not diminish the others, but showing totals this way is seldom as informative as using a stacked column chart.